# Bash script get/extract specific info/word from a line

Tags: command-line, nvidia, text-processing

the command `nvcc --version` outputs the following:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_21:14:42_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

I'm trying to get the cuda version which in this case is `10.2` from the 4th line.

Therefore i tried the following:

```
cudaVersion="$(nvcc --version| grep 'Cuda compilation ')"
echo "$cudaVersion"
```

this gives me however the whole line as an output. However i just want to assign the version to `cudaVersion`

I believe this must work with `cut`, however i can't get it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` with Perl regex support (`grep -P`):

```
$ nvcc --version | grep -Po 'release \K\d+\.\d+'
11.2
```

- `-o` prints only the matched text.
- `release \K` looks for the string `release` followed by a space, then excludes that from the match (`\K`) so that only the part after `\K` is included in the matched text.
- The part after `\K` is `\d+` (at least one digit) followed by a
  period (`\.`) followed by at least one digit (`\d+`), matching the actual version number.